# ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized Error

Tags: asp.net, ado.net

I have a error of ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized Line 28: gvEmployeeDetail.DataSource = cmdSelectWithUsername.ExecuteReader();

```
 ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized
Line 28:          gvEmployeeDetail.DataSource = cmdSelectWithUsername.ExecuteReader();
```

My Code is here

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["New"] != null)
        {
            string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
            {
                lblUserNamed.Text = Session["New"].ToString();
                SqlCommand cmdSelectWithUsername = new SqlCommand("select* from tblEmployeeDetail where UserName = @username ");

                cmdSelectWithUsername.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", lblUserNamed.Text);
                con.Open();
                gvEmployeeDetail.DataSource = cmdSelectWithUsername.ExecuteReader();
                gvEmployeeDetail.DataBind();

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign connection to command

**Like :**

```
SqlCommand cmdSelectWithUsername = new SqlCommand("select* from tblEmployeeDetail where
   UserName = @username ", con);
```